# assignment of read-only location - Boost Geometry Register Point 2D

Tags: c++, struct, boost, nodes, boost-geometry

I am currently trying to implement a motion-planning algorithm and have been using Boost's RTree to do so. Up until now, the RTree has stored `std::pair<boost::geometry::model::point<double, 2, bg::cs::cartesian>, unsigned int>` and has worked just fine in answering nearest neighbor queries.
Externally, I make use of a custom struct called `Node`, each of which corresponds to a point in the RTree. I maintain a `vector` of `Node`s so that the ids of the output pairs from the RTree queries can be used as indices to be looked up in the vector.

However, I want to eliminate the use of this large vector to see its results on time and space performance of my algorithm. To do this, I want to replace the use of `point` in the `pair`s with `Node`s, so that the `Node`s are directly output in the query results. To do this I have used boost geometry 2d point registering, with the following code:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/point.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/box.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/register/point.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/index/rtree.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;

namespace bg = boost::geometry;
namespace bgi = boost::geometry::index;

typedef bg::model::point<double, 2, bg::cs::cartesian> point;
typedef bg::model::box<point> box;

struct Node
{
  Node *parent;
  point pos;
};

typedef pair<Node, unsigned int> ptval;
typedef pair<box, unsigned int> boxval;

BOOST_GEOMETRY_REGISTER_POINT_2D(Node, double, bg::cs::cartesian, pos.get<0>(), pos.get<1>());

int main() {
  cout << "hi" << endl; return 0;
}
```

However, a strange error results:

```
In file included from rrt.cpp:13:
rrt.cpp: In static member function 'static void boost::geometry::traits::access<Node, 0>::set(Node&, const double&)':       
rrt.cpp:45:1: error: assignment of read-only location 'p.Node::pos.boost::geometry::model::point<double, 2, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian>::get<0>()'
 BOOST_GEOMETRY_REGISTER_POINT_2D(Node, double, bg::cs::cartesian, pos.get<0>(), pos.get<1>());
```

This is odd as there are no const declarations anywhere here. I'm guessing it has to do with something inside of the hood of the get<>() functions, but I'm not sure exactly what it is.

Any help is appreciated, as I've not found this issue anywhere online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of boost is that? [`BOOST_GEOMETRY_REGISTER_POINT_2D_GET_SET`](https://live.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/adapted/register/boost_geometry_register_point_2d_get_set.html) takes 7 parameters, not 5, and it has done so ever since the source file appeared in January 2010, which means Boost 1.47.0.

Looking at the docs, it looks like the `()` are not supposed to be included on the member functions anyways.

Finally, you have `bg::get<0>` in your question code, but since that doesn't even match with the error message you show, I'm assuming that's a simple mistake in the question.

Here's a little test program with the fixes I think you wanted:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f26023edf3425b6c)**

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/box.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/point.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/register/point.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/index/rtree.hpp>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

namespace bg  = boost::geometry;
namespace bgi = boost::geometry::index;

typedef bg::model::point<double, 2, bg::cs::cartesian> point;
typedef bg::model::box<point>                          box;

struct Node {
    Node* parent;
    point pos;
};

using ptval  = std::pair<Node, unsigned int>;
using boxval = std::pair<box, unsigned int>;

BOOST_GEOMETRY_REGISTER_POINT_2D_GET_SET( //
    Node, double, bg::cs::cartesian,      //
    pos.get<0>, pos.get<1>, pos.set<0>, pos.set<1>)

int main() {
    {
        bgi::rtree<ptval, bgi::rstar<16>> index;

        Node n{nullptr, {}};
        bg::assign_values(n.pos, 10.0, 10.0);

        int idx = 0;
        index.insert({n, idx++});

        for (auto pt : { point{20.0, 10.0}, {20.0, 20.0}, {10.0, 20.0} }) {
            bg::assign(n.pos, pt);
            index.insert({n, idx++});
        }

        for (auto& [g, id] : index) {
            std::cout << id << ": " << bg::wkt(g) << '\n';
        }
    }
    { 
        bgi::rtree<boxval, bgi::rstar<16>> index;
        index.insert(boxval{{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, 12});
        for (auto& [g, id] : index) {
            std::cout << id << ": " << bg::wkt(g) << '\n';
        }
    }
}
```

Printing

```
0: POINT(10 10)
1: POINT(20 10)
2: POINT(20 20)
3: POINT(10 20)
12: POLYGON((1 2,1 4,3 4,3 2,1 2))
```

Comment: added output to verify that the accessors are actually working as required

Comment: Yes, sorry I may have been a bit lazy in copypasting.... The code works fine. Kind of underwhelming that the fix was just a pair of parentheses...

Comment: Being accurate saves time :) But glad it works now